# Two full text mysql searches with union but return a distinct field

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

```
SELECT DISTINCT sectionID FROM (
  (SELECT sectionID,MATCH (content) AGAINST ('blah') AS relevance
   FROM sectioncontent WHERE MATCH (content) AGAINST ('blah')) AS alias

  UNION DISTINCT

  (SELECT sectionID,MATCH (name, description) AGAINST ('blah') AS relevance
   FROM sections WHERE MATCH (name, description) AGAINST ('blah'))  
)
```

I would eventually use GROUP BY and ORDER BY but I can't get the above to work. Any point to the right direction would be much appreciated, thanks!

This is what I was originally using, but it would return two results with same sectionID (one from the section table and one from the sectioncontent table) since the relevance fields were not the same.

```
(SELECT sectionID,MATCH (content) AGAINST ('blah') AS relevance
 FROM sectioncontent WHERE MATCH (content) AGAINST ('blah')) 

UNION DISTINCT 

(SELECT sectionID,MATCH (name, description) AGAINST ('blah') AS relevance
 FROM sections WHERE MATCH (name, description) AGAINST ('blah'))
ORDER BY relevance DESC


sectionID relevance
32        6.42576837539673
32        2.10306763648987
```

Comment: Can you provide an alter table for your two tables, so I may create them locally?

Comment: Can you explain in more detail, why your are unioning your table to itself?

Comment: Unsure what you mean by alter.  What I have is two tables, sections and section content.  Sections has the section name, description and some other fields that pertain to the section.

Comment: Sorry premature enter...Section content holds the content of the section.  They both share the same section ID, where sectionID is the primary for sections and the primary for sectioncontent is contentID.  So I am doing a full text search on a keyword, but I want it to be able to search the name and description (sections) and the actual content (sectioncontent) but I don't want to have two results with the same sectionID.  adding as relevance makes it do that but I need that to order by relevance.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Oh, I am not trying to union the table to itself, one table is sections, the other is section content.

Comment: I apologize, the above query doesn't work at all.  This is what I was using before that was resulting in two rows with the same sectionID if the keyword was in name or description and content.  (SELECT sectionID,MATCH (content) AGAINST ('teen') AS relevance FROM sectioncontent WHERE MATCH (content) AGAINST ('teen'))
    
  UNION DISTINCT
    
  (SELECT sectionID,MATCH (name, description) AGAINST ('teen') AS relevance FROM sections WHERE MATCH (name, description) AGAINST ('teen'))

Comment: RESULTS
sectionID  relevance

32  2.10306763648987

32  6.42576837539673

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, here is the solution for anyone else who may come across this

```
SELECT sectionID,sum(relevance) FROM (

SELECT sectionID,MATCH(content) AGAINST ('blah') as relevance
FROM sectioncontent WHERE MATCH(content) AGAINST ('blah')

UNION

SELECT sectionID ,MATCH(name,description) AGAINST ('blah') as relevance
FROM sections WHERE MATCH(name,description) AGAINST ('blah')

) as tmptable GROUP BY sectionID ORDER BY relevance DESC
```